# BuddyPress - How to display posts created by friends?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

In WordPress with BuddyPress, how can I display for a user posts (custom post type) that are created by his friends only?

Not as/in activity steam (it's disabled on the site), but as usual loop `while(have_posts()):`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$friend_ids = friends_get_friend_user_ids( bp_loggedin_user_id() );

if ( ! empty( $friend_ids ) {

   $args = array(
       'author__in' => $friend_ids
   ); 

   $query = new WP_Query( $args );

}
```

Adjust `$args` to include other parameters like `post_type`.  And then create a `while` loop.